# Distinct Route Pairs

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find a way to get distinctive pairs.

Suppose the table has 3 fields: id, city1 and city2.

Sample Data:
1, New York, Los Angeles
2, New York, Philadelphia
3, New York, Houston
4, Los Angeles, New York
5, Los Angeles, Houston
6, Houston, New York
7, Houston, Los Angeles

I would like the output to only include distinct pairs, regardless of the order of which column position they are in.

Sample Output:
New York, Los Angeles
New York, Philadelphia
New York, Houston
Los Angeles, Houston

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT city1, city2 FROM YourTable WHERE city1 < city2 
    UNION SELECT city2, city1 FROM YourTable T1 WHERE city1 > city2
```

Make sure *not* to use the ALL keyword after the UNION so that the UNION will drop out duplicates from the result set.

Comment: My example gives the correct list of city pairs as you requested, but it always has the "lowest" city in the first column.  Therefore all but NY, Phila come out "backwards" in my example.  I presume that is satisfactory for your needs.